# On click of Activate button I need to call customized workflow in CQ5?

Tags: aem

On click of Activate button i need to call some other customized workflow, Where do i need to do the modifications, Which are the files involved in this in cq5 version 6.

Answer (score 2):

Intercepting activate button click is quite intrusive therefore should be done on `Filter` level. You can write an example OSGi component class:

```
@Component(immediate = true)
@Service
@Properties({ @Property(name = "filter.scope", value = "REQUEST") })
public class MyCustomReplicationFilter implements Filter {
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {
        SlingHttpServletRequest slingRequest = (SlingHttpServletRequest) request;
        if ("/bin/replicate.json".equals(slingRequest.getPathInfo())) {
            List<String> paths = Lists.newArrayList(request.getParameterValues("path"));
            //do magic with your paths. E.g. invoke workflow
        }
    }
```

Alternatively you can change the ootb siteadmin panel (`/siteadmin`) and change the behaviour of `Activate` button to send a request to your dedicated servlet.